# Чем отличается вычисление лямбда-выражения от вычисления тела лямбда-выражения?

Tags: java, лямбда-выражение

Чем отличается вычисление лямбда-выражения от вычисления тела лямбда-выражения?

Answer (score 2):

> Вычисление лямбда-выражения создает экземпляр функционального
>   интерфейса (§9.8). Вычисление лямбда-выражения не приводит к
>   вычислению тела выражения; оно может осуществиться позже, когда будет
>   вызван соответствующий метод функционального интерфейса.

*Гослинг Д., Джой Б., Стил Г., Брача Г., Бакли А. - Язык программирования Java SE 8. Подробное описание, 5-е издание - 2015 (стр 560)*

Comment: Не забудьте принять свой ответ

Answer (score 1):

Ничем, когда вы вычисляете лямда-выражение, вы вычисляете выражение в его теле.